# How to input Chinese character partially?

Tags: characters, input-methods

I am looking for a method to input Chinese character partially. For example, the first three strokes of (木), or the last three strokes of (五).

I would like to write an article on Wang Zhao mandarin letters. Those letters are parts of Chinese characters, but not necessarilly a radical.

Comment: What do you mean by "input" here? I doubt there is a font that can display an arbitrary set of strokes from any given character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Chinese is severely limited by what has been added to unicode on computers, even the vast majority of characters are impossible to output on any keyboard, let alone these arbitrary sections-- hopefully in the future that will change.

There are only three reasonable options to indicate this sectioning currently:

The first option is simply showing the strokes, like 一丨丿。This is a good choice if the character is firmly established, but does nothing to show the actual shape clearly.

The second option is simply saying "first three strokes of 木。" This conveys the concept perfectly, but still doesn't show the visual.

The third is the most work, which is to handwrite the chracter/shape/etc and insert it as a photo at the same size as the regular typed text.  Whether a dictionary, a textbook, or the daily news; this is how you will see it done.  Here is an example of it being done in a textbook on oracle bone script 《Oracle bone incriptions from Huayuanzhuang east, A. SCHWARTZ 》:

[image]

And another from a dictionary specializing in showing untypable characters online 《國學大師》：[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:**

If you don't want to type Chinese in 拼音pinyin, I guess you are looking for 五笔输入法 or 仓颉输入法。But I don't think so…because it's quite hard to learn a new input method. Many middle-aged people, those in their 40s, use 五笔 input method, and they learned this at that time. Nowadays, many young people use Pinyin input method because 五笔 is no longer taught in schools.

This is 百度输入法（pinyin input method）
[image]

This is 五笔输入法（Five input methods / five-stroke input method）

[image]

**Answer 2:**

If you mean, you want to type 一丨丿丶乛亅乙乚乁乀ㄑしㄋ┐∟ㄥ讠礻饣衤忄丬阝扌牜亻彳犭丷艹亠冖宀爫癶耂罒覀疒…… you can download a pinyin input method, better like 搜狗输入法 or 百度输入法, then you can find this

[image]
[image]

or type them by writing
[image]

or find a website with all the Chinese strokes, then ctrl+c  ctrl+v  to use them

**Answer 3:**

I don't think there is a Chinese character that only have the first three strokes of 木, so you can't type them. If you need to show this in an article, better to show it in a picture. Also use photoshop to show what you need.

You can get the strokes animation in this: http://bishun.strokeorder.info/